# 1004 Error: Cannot reset variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a very simple thing. I want to store a range of dynamic values in a variable. I use the following code:

```
Sub Main()
Set RawStuff = Worksheets("Data Input").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
End Sub
```

The first time works fine, the second time I run it produces the following error:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

The only way to fix it is by restarting excel/exiting the workbook.

My guess is that the issue is that once a variable is set, it cannot be reset. For reference, I am creating this macro for a specific workbook.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set RawStuff = Worksheets("Data Input").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

This will fail if "Data Input" is not active, since by default `Range("A1")` will refer to the active sheet.

It's best to qualify all calls to `Range()` or `Cells()` with a worksheet object:

```
With Worksheets("Data Input")
    Set RawStuff = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
End With
```

The code above should work regardless of which worksheet is active (as long as the active workbook is the correct one)

Comment: So every time I have to store a variable, the worksheet where the cells are has to be activated?

Comment: No - you just have to be specific whenever you use Range() , or Cells() since by default they always refer to the active sheet

Comment: Hey Tim, I think you're missing a `With`?

Comment: I modified the comment so that it begins with 'With' and ends with 'End With', as per nbayly's suggestions. The error however is still appearing. Tim, your note about the active sheet appears to be right, but I'd like it so the user does not have to have 'Data Input' as the active sheet.

Comment: Thanks @nbayly - added that

Comment: @macworthy - If the code above still gives problems, it may be because the user has also changed workbooks and is therefore calling your macro while there is no `Worksheets("Data Input")` to access.  If that is so, change `With Worksheets("Data Input")` to `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Input")` (assuming that the "Data Input" sheet is in the workbook that contains the macros).

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for your help. I am still getting the error, strangely. Again, only when "Data Input" is selected does the macro work. Is there way to look through all the worksheets and make "Data Input" active?

Comment: @macworthy - Why do you want to make "Data Input" active?  (It's easy to do - `Worksheets("Data Input").Activate` - but definitely not good practice to do so.)

Comment: @YowE3K The issue is that I want the user to be able to open the workbook and then run the macro regardless of the page. The macro involves doing calculations on multiple pages with information flowing between pages. It's not a huge issue, but I want to make it user friendly.

Comment: @macworthy - That is why you should avoid `Activate` and `Select` (etc) like the plague, and always qualify all `Range`, `Cell`, `Rows` etc objects with the worksheet that they refer to.  The code in Tim's answer should work providing the ActiveWorkbook contains a sheet called "Data Input".  Is that the line that is causing the error, or is it another line in your code that is crashing now?

Comment: @macworthy - Ahhh - I just thought of something - you said "I want the user to be able to open the workbook and then run the macro" - do you have the call of `Main` in a `Workbook_Open` event?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm fairly new to VBA/Macros and am still trying to understand how they operate within the workbook.